# Populate dataset using stored procedure with Oracle 12c client fails

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I have inherited a C# application which uses **Executedataset** method to populate a dataset from an Oracle 11g DB. The stored procedure is a part of a PL/SQL package and currently has **3 OUT cursors**. I use **Oracle 11g client** on all the client machines. We have a need to use **Oracle 12c** client going forward. However, after I installed Oracle 12c, the ExecuteDataset method fails with the exception "**number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure**". On my research I found that I would have to use only **one** **OUT CURSOR**. I also tried doing that and with that although the Stored proc returns data as seen through the SQL developer debug session, I am not able to return that in my application.

Below is my simple call that works to get data with Oracle 11g:

```
    DataSet ds = DB.ExecuteDataSet("MY_PKG.GET_VALUES", Month,Yr, 
                                   null,null,null);
```

null values are for OUT REF cursors

Below is the original Stored procedure definition:

```
    PROCEDURE GET_VALUES (
     PI_MONTH IN MDETAIL.MONTH%TYPE,
     PI_YR IN MDETAIL.YR%TYPE,
     CUR_OUT1 IN OUT MY_PKG.refcur,
     CUR_OUT2 IN OUT MY_PKG.refcur,
     CUR_OUT3 IN OUT MY_PKG.refcur
    );
```

I modified the procedure definition to return just one SYS_REFCURSOR:

```
    PROCEDURE GET_VALUES ( 
      PI_MONTH IN MDETAIL.MONTH%TYPE,
      PI_YR IN MDETAIL.YR%TYPE,
      CUR_OUT IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    );
```

Below is my modified call that does NOT work to get data with Oracle 12c:

```
    DataSet ds = DB.ExecuteDataSet("MY_PKG.GET_VALUES", Month,Yr,null);
```

I am not sure where is the parameter mismatch happening? It would be great if someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try without comma after "SYS_REFCURSOR"

Comment: Sorry it's a typo in the question. I don't have a comma in the code. I have edited it.